# Appending to JSON is causing error

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to append the ID of a `setInterval` function to a JSON file, but it gets me an error `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

My code looks like this

```
var clearID = setInterval(function(){
   //do stuff
},(60)*1000);

fs.readFile('path', 'utf8', function readFileCallback(err, data){
   if (err) return console.log(err);   
     var doc = JSON.parse(data);
     doc.IDs.shift();
     doc.IDs.push(clearID);
     var saved = JSON.stringify(doc);
  fs.writeFile('path', saved, 'utf8', (err)=>{
    if(err) return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

What should I change to stop this error?

Comment: I think the problem is with **meusfeeds**, what is its contents?

Comment: Can you give an example of your data?

Comment: Why would you want to put an interval id in a file? Anyway, if the idea is just to update the existing file it should be `var saved = JSON.stringify(doc);`, since `doc` refers to the object you've just modified.

Comment: @A.J my bad, i forgot to change this in the question, but in my code is `var saved = JSON.stringify(doc)`

Comment: @israel.zinc yeah, it has some arrays, and IDs is one of them `{"array1":[],"array2":[],"IDs":[0]}`

Comment: @nnnnnn this code is in a function outside my main file, so I'd like to save the ID to clear the interval outside the function... It seems more confusing when I try to explain, but it did make sense to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a NodeJS environment, you simply can't convert the return value of a `setInterval` call to JSON string. The error you get is very clear, the return value contains one or more circular references.

Try this (in a node environment):

```
var x = setInterval(function() { },100);
console.log(x);
```

See the circular references? They show up as `[Circular]`

In a browser environment, you'd get a number returned from `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, not the case when these functions are executed in node.

[NodeJS timers documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args)

[Browser timers documentation (e.g. setTimeout)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Comment: I see... is there another way I could save this value to use it outside my function?

Comment: @LostWoods - not in a string, you can save it in memory in some sort of data structure you define, but that's about it.